# C++ Linked Lists: "->" operator fails to change the internal values of node object

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to code a doubly linked list in c++, but I am running into a problem. When I append a number in linked lists, it works fine, but after constructing an array of linked lists, the append function no longer works. Somehow the header of each linked list loses their link. Here is my code (scroll all the way to the bottom to find my current theories/diagnoses):

linked list code:

```
#include "linkedList.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

linkedList::node::node(int value)
{
    internalValue = value;
    next = nullptr;
    previous = nullptr;
};

linkedList::linkedList()
: header{node(-2)}, trailer{node(-2)}
{
    trailer.previous = &header;
    header.next = &trailer;
    size = 0;
}

int linkedList::getLength()
{
    return size;
}

void linkedList::appendElement(int value)
{

    node * newNode = new node(value);
    newNode->next = &trailer;
    newNode->previous = trailer.previous;
    // ------------------------------------------------------
    node * address = trailer.previous;
    address->next = newNode;
    // ------------------------------------------------------
    trailer.previous = newNode;
    size = size + 1;

}


void linkedList::print()
{
    node * current = header.next;
    std::string listOfValues;
    while (current -> next != nullptr)
    {
        //std::cout << current -> internalValue << "->";
        listOfValues = listOfValues + "->" + std::to_string(current -> internalValue);
        current = current->next;
    }

    listOfValues = listOfValues + "->_ ";
    std::cout << listOfValues << "\n";

}

int linkedList::getElementAt(int index)
{

    if (index < 0 || index >= size)
    {
        throw std::out_of_range ("Out of Range");
    }
    else
    {
        int count = index;
        node * current = &header;
        while (count > 0)
        {
            current = current -> next;
            count = count - 1;
        }
        return current -> next -> internalValue;
    }
}
```

linked list header code:

```
#ifndef linkedList_hpp
#define linkedList_hpp

class linkedList
{

protected:

private:
    class node
    {

    public:
        node(int value);
        int internalValue;
        node * next;
        node * previous;

    };

    int size;
    node trailer;
    node header;

public:
    explicit linkedList();
    int getLength();
    void appendElement(int value);
    void print();
    int getElementAt(int index);



};
#endif /* linkedList_hpp */
```

inserting numbers into the list works:

```
linkedList list1;
list1.appendElement(42);
list1.appendElement(99);
list1.print();

// prints ->42->99->_
```

inserting into a list in an array does not work:

```
linkedList list2;
linkedList list_array[1] = { list2 };
list_array[0].appendElement(42);
list_array[0].appendElement(99);
list_array[0].print();

// prints ->_
```

My work so far:
So if you look at the first code, specifically the area I separated using "--------", I introduced a little redundancy with the variable "address" so that I could see what was happening. What appears to happen is when I insert a new Node into the linked list via the append function, the "header.next" field does not get updated. When I checked the debugger, the variable "address" has the same memory location as "header", but using the "->" operator on address to access header.next did not update header.next. I don't understand why that is. If I have the memory location of header and use "->", I thought it should give me header.next? Can someone point me in the right direction please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: first suspect: your list does not implement rule of 3 (or 5), and that will make it misbehave when put in a container

Comment: Why does `chainHashTable` contain 20 `linkedList`s?

Comment: @aschepler 20? I thought there are only 10

Comment: @sp2danny, sorry but I didn't quite understand (I am very new to c++). After reading about the rule of 3 and rule of 5, its my understanding that if you implement one of the things specified in the rule, then you should implement the others. I don't think I implemented any of those things?

Comment: His hash table handles collisions by storing them in a list. It's not relevant to the question. There is a ton of stuff not relevant to the question, while the actual linked list (where the problem is) is not even shown. Is should be easy for abid to strip all that stuff, append two things to a linked list, and provide a reproduction.

Comment: @KennyOstrom, isn't the first one the linked list? Also the append works when using the linked list by itself. It only has the problem when stored in the hash list. That's why I attached the rest. I'll try and attach a reproduction.

Comment: We need the header. It will help with what sp2danny said in the first comment.

Comment: The -> operator doesn't change anything. The = operator does that.

Comment: @KennyOstrom, I added the header file, and also some output

Comment: @EJP, you're correct. I should have worded that better. Yes I realize that -> doesn't do anything by itself. I have used the "=" operator in conjunction with the ->. Its just that internal variable doesn't become what I set it to become, and I believe its because somehow the -> is not getting to the right field.

Comment: May I edit your question with a vastly simplified form of chainHashTable, pretty much eliminating that part? I reproduced with just an array of linkedList

Comment: Yes you may!   extra character

Comment: I think that I might have just fixed the code, I simply changed the list of linked lists into a list of linked list pointers. It seems to run perfectly fine now, but i need to test further. I will post what happens with the tests.

Comment: You will still want the fix for this bug. Edit is submitted. I just got rid of chainHashTable and posted a simplified reproduction.

Comment: That is true. Good point.

Comment: @AbidRizvi : when you are putting stuff in a container (or array), you are making copies, so the copy-constructor or the assignment operator will be called. if you don't provide those, they will be default generated. the default generated ones do member-wise (shallow) copy, which is not correct for a linked list, for example; back pointers will point to the head of another list

Comment: there are excellent guides in [so-documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/1206/the-rule-of-three-five-and-zero#t=201612022019251802446)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array constructs a new instance of linkedList, which is why you fixed it by changing it to array of pointers.

When linkedList was copied into a new instance for the array, it performed a shallow copy of the header and trailer nodes.  The node class contains pointers, and therefore must implement a copy constructor to avoid this shallow copy.

The immediate bug in this code is fixed by adding/deleting these copy constructors. I didn't do all the copy, which you really must.

```
// we don't want to copy the pointers from one node to a new node
// otherwise things get double deleted and you crash, later,
// when you start implementing the destructors
// so just make it impossible to copy a node
class node {
private:
    node(const node &ref); // use delete syntax from c++11 if available
public:
    node(int value);
    ...

linkedList::linkedList(const linkedList &ref)
    : header{-1}, trailer{-2}
{
    trailer.previous = &header;
    header.next = &trailer;
    size = 0;
    // now append a copy of every data node from ref
}
```

Additionally, rule of three implies some more things you must implement, and you really needed the destructor on linkedList anyway, because you create new nodes, but never destroy them.

Additional note: I changed header(node{-1}) to header{-1} because it is no longer possible to copy nodes, so that temporary object can't be used to copy into header.  But you didn't need it anyway.